# How to connect to Firebird embedded with SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, firebird, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to connect to firebird(embedded version) with Flask-SQLAlchemy but I keep geting the error :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError) ('Error while connecting to database:\n- SQLCODE: -902\n- Unable to complete network request to host "127.0.0.1".\n- Failed to establish a connection.', -902, 335544721)
```

My connection variable is:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI ='firebird://sysdba:masterkey@127.0.0.1:3050/' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data.gdb')
```

I also tried with localhost, same error.

Any clue what I am doing wrong?

This is on Windows 7 using firebird 2.5 ,Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.0 and SQLAlchemy==1.0.3

I also tried without supplying a username password since it's the embedded verion, still not working

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI ='firebird://127.0.0.1:3050/' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data.gdb')
```

Comment: You are trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 (localhost), so you are not trying to connect to a Firebird embedded instance, but to an actual server (which isn't running, hence the error). You might want to try leaving the hostname and portnumber out, but I am not actually sure if using firebird embedded is even supported.

Comment: Ah, that might explain it.  And indeed not using localhost and the port isn't working.  It actually extract my computer name and tries to connect to it.  That's a dang shame, I need to use an embedded database but SQLite is causing problem with it's lack of support for ALTER.   Well, back to doing research.

Comment: Firebird embedded might work, but you may need to rename fbembed.dll to fbclient.dll (and put it on the path of python) to get it to work.

Comment: That's was done already.  Without renaming the dll it would actually look into the registry and give another error.  That forced me to read the actual doc :P

Comment: The Firebird embedded DLL is actually firebird client + database engine; if FDB always specifies a hostname, then it will behave like a normal fbclient.dll. I have looked if FDB actually supports Firebird embedded, but I couldn't find anything conclusive.

Comment: I asked my question on the sqlalchemy mailing list to see if there is a solution to connect to the embedded version of firebird.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error until I changed value of `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` to `firebird+fdb://login_on_firebird:password_on_firebird@localhost:3050/ + os.path.join(basedir, 'data.gdb')`. Also, you need to create the special user on firebird server